# print out the last 10 lines of a file

Tags: c++, file, cout, tail

I want to have the option to print out the last 10 lines of a textfile . with this program I've been able to read the whole textfile, but I can't figure out how to manipulate the array in which the textfile is saved, any help?

```
// Textfile output
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i=1;
    char zeile[250], file[50];
    cout << "filename:" << flush;
    cin.get(file,50);                          ///// (1)
    ifstream eingabe(datei , ios::in);          /////(2)
    if (eingabe.good() ) {                       /////(3)           
       eingabe.seekg(0L,ios::end);               ////(4)
       cout << "file:"<< file << "\t"
            << eingabe.tellg() << " Bytes"       ////(5)
            << endl;
       for (int j=0; j<80;j++)
           cout << "_";
           cout << endl;
       eingabe.seekg(0L, ios::beg);              ////(6)
       while (!eingabe.eof() ){                  ///(7)
             eingabe.getline(zeile,250);         ///(8)
             cout << setw(2) << i++
                  << ":" << zeile << endl;
             }      
           }
    else
        cout <<"dateifehler oder Datei nicht gefunden!"
             << endl;
            
             return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Although you probably already know this, the unix [tail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix)) command does exactly what you want.

Comment: @darioo: this question sounds like homework.

Comment: BTW, you'll find it **much** faster on larger files if you seek to the end of the file and then seek backwards to find your start point, rather parsing the entire file.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
```

// A class that knows how to read a line using operator >>

```
struct Line
{
    std::string theLine;
    operator std::string const& () const { return theLine; }
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Line& l)
    {
        return std::getline(stream, l.theLine);
    }
};
```

// A circular buffer that only saves the last n lines.

```
class Buffer
{
    public:
        Buffer(size_t lc)
            : lineCount(lc)
        {}
        void push_back(std::string const& line)
        {
            buffer.insert(buffer.end(),line);
            if (buffer.size() > lineCount)
            {
                buffer.erase(buffer.begin());
            }
        }
        typedef std::list<std::string>      Cont;
        typedef Cont::const_iterator        const_iterator;
        typedef Cont::const_reference       const_reference;
        const_iterator begin()  const       { return buffer.begin(); }
        const_iterator end()    const       { return buffer.end();}

    private:
        size_t                      lineCount;
        std::list<std::string>      buffer;
};
```

// Main

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream   file("Plop");
    Buffer          buffer(10);

    // Copy the file into the special buffer.
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Line>(file), std::istream_iterator<Line>(),
            std::back_inserter(buffer));

    // Copy the buffer (which only has the last 10 lines)
    // to std::cout
    std::copy(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you are not saving the file contents to any array.  The following sample will give you a head start:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main ( int, char ** )
{
    // Ask user for path to file.
    std::string path;
    std::cout << "filename:";
    std::getline(std::cin, path);

    // Open selected file.      
    std::ifstream file(path.c_str());
    if ( !file.is_open() )
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open '" << path << "'." << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Read lines (note: stores all of it in memory, might not be your best option).
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    for ( std::string line; std::getline(file,line); )
    {
        lines.push_back(line);
    }

    // Print out (up to) last ten lines.
    for ( std::size_t i = std::min(lines.size(), std::size_t(10)); i < lines.size(); ++i )
    {
        std::cout << lines[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It would probably be wiser to avoid storing the whole file into memory, so you could re-write the last 2 segments this way:

```
// Read up to 10 lines, accumulating.
std::deque<std::string> lines;
for ( std::string line; lines.size() < 0 && getline(file,line); )
{
    lines.push_back(line);
}

// Read the rest of the file, adding one, dumping one.
for ( std::string line; getline(file,line); )
{
    lines.pop_front();
    lines.push_back(line);
}

// Print out whatever is left (up to 10 lines).
for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i )
{
    std::cout << lines[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The eof() function does not do what you and it seems a million other C++ newbies think it does. It does NOT predict if the next read will work. In C++ as in any other language, you must check the status of each read operation, not the state of the input stream before the read. so the canonical C++ read line loop is:

```
while ( eingabe.getline(zeile,250) ) {
    // do something with zeile
}
```

Also, you should be reading into a `std::string`, and get rid of that 250 value.

Answer (score 0):

Do a circular buffer with 10 slots and while reading the file lines, putting them into this buffer. When you finish thr file, do a position++ to go to the first element and print them all.
Pay attention for null values if the file has less than 10 lines.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have an array of strings with size 10.
2. Read the first line and store into the array
3. Continue reading till the array is full
4. Once the array is full delete the first entry so that you can enter new line
   Repeate step 3 and 4 till the file is finished reading.

Answer (score 0):

I investigate proposed approaches here and describe all in my blog post. There is a better solution but you have to jump to the end and persist all needed lines:

```
std::ifstream hndl(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::ate);
// and use handler in function which iterate backward
void print_last_lines_using_circular_buffer(std::ifstream& stream, int lines)
{
    circular_buffer<std::string> buffer(lines);

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<line>(stream),
              std::istream_iterator<line>(),
              std::back_inserter(buffer));

    std::copy(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout));
}
```